# SugarCRM - Prevent record for a customized module

Tags: database, module, sugarcrm

I would like to be able to create a module as an interaction between sugarCRM and an other database. For that I built a module thanks to the module builder tool, and I would like to connect it to a new table which is a join between sugar data and my second app data (to prevent data duplication).

As my new table for the module is a view between two others, sugar views the content without any problem, but throws an exception whenever I try to insert anything. So I would like to use a logic hook who will directly store the data within the two "original" tables.

Here is my problem : even if the data are correctly stored, I would like to prevent sugar to try to store anything. Is there something I can do within my hook to stop sugar action, once my hook finished its job ?

Sorry for my terrible english and thanks for reading.

Comment: To make sure I understand: you used Module Builder to create a module that Sugar will recognize, but the data for that module comes from an external source, and Sugar should only ever _read_ from that module's table, because it's not a real table anyway, just a view. Is that correct? And the specific question doesn't have to do with the logic hook to store the data in the real tables, but solely with preventing the custom module from ever trying to save anything using Sugar's default module code. Right?

Comment: Sorry for answering so late, I don't use often this account... You understood, I force Sugar to think the view is its own table, so that Sugar reads correctly the data. Then, when something is edited, I use a logic hooks to retrieve the interesting data and update them in the first table. But then with this method Sugar tries to update the view (which he considers as his own table) and that's what  disturbs me, because Sugar crashes then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I recommend is overriding the Save method in your custom module's controller.

Once you build and deploy the module, there will be a new directory: `custom/modules/yourcustommodule`. In that directory, create a file named `controller.php`.

That file should include the following (**untested**) code:

```
require_once('include/MVC/Controller/SugarController.php');

class yourcustommoduleController extends SugarController {
    function action_save() {
        return;
    }
}
```

You could even move your before/after hooks into this custom action function. As long as you don't call the default save method (`parent::action_save();` I think), SugarCRM's default save action(s) won't happen.

**Important:** after deploying a custom module, SugarCRM's best practice is to never redeploy it, but to make all subsequent changes in Studio. This is important because once you make these file-level changes to a custom module, those changes would be lost if you redeploy the module.

Comment: That note about deployment is very important. In Module Builder, just get the fields and relationships designed, then Publish it, install the published version, and delete the copy in Module Builder. Just get out of Moule Builder as quickly as possible. On the OP approach to this, replacing the module's table with a view is a great way to make data available to the APIs that would not otherwise be available. We have metadata in the joining tables of some relationships, and a view is able to pull that into the selected Entries for us. Very handy technique.